# Prove binary tree properties using induction

Tags: binary-tree, nodes, proof, induction

I am having trouble proving binary tree properties using induction:

```
Property 1 - A tree with N internal nodes has a maximum height of N+1
    base case - 0 internal nodes has a height of 0
    assume - a tree with k internal nodes has a maximum height of k+1 where k exists in n
    show - true for all k+1 or true for all k-1

Property 2 - A tree with a tree with N internal nodes has N + 1 leaf nodes
    base case - 0 internal nodes has 1 leaf node (null)
    assume - a tree with k internal nodes has k + 1 leaf nodes where k exists in n
    show - true for all k+1 or true for all k-1
```

Is my setup correct? And if so, how do I actually show these things. Everything I have tried has just ended up becoming a mess. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a few things.

For property 1, your base case must be consistent with what you're trying to prove.  So a tree with 0 internal nodes must have a height of at most 0+1=1.  This is true: consider a tree with only a root.

For the inductive step, consider a tree with k-1 internal nodes.  If its height is at most k (assumed), adding one more node can only raise it to k+1, and no higher.  So the k-internal-node tree has height at most k+1.

Property 2 is false.  Counterexample:

```
    5
  4  6
 3    7
2      8
```

5 internal nodes, 2 leaves.

So there's probably something different you wanted to prove.

Comment: Hey, forgot that the second property is for a perfect binary tree (thus at level 4 you would have 7 internal nodes and 8 leaves. Thank you for the response.